# Cascading Drop Down giving 'Undefined' values in Chrome and blank fields

Tags: asp.net, sql, cascadingdropdown

I am developing a web form that uses WebService to populate data for the DropDownList by use of Ajax Cascading DropDown.
While debugging it in VS with its own instance of IIS Express, it worked like a charm. When I installed IIS on localhost to perform full testing, the dropdown gets populated with 'undefined' values in Chrome and blank fields in IE.

I provide the full code below. Both the form and the WebService reside in a folder named Query. I checked the path for the CascadingDropDown. When I change it to anything else, the field returns Method 500 error. The path that I use, therefore, is correct, since this error is not thrown.

In the code, you will come accross "NoValidationDropDown", please overlook this, this is not source of error and only allows to bypass validation.

I have not made any changes to WebConfig. Please let me know if this is important for WebServices to work.
I have allowed TCP/IP connection to my SQL express server database instance.

This is an excerpt from my form page (Data_selector.aspx):

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server">
        <p>
            <b>Query Type</b><br />
            <asp:NoValidationDropDown ID="ddlquery" runat="server"/>
            <%--<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlquery" runat="server"/>--%>
            <ajaxtoolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="ccdquery" runat="server" Category="QueryType" TargetControlID="ddlquery"
            PromptText="Please select a query" LoadingText="Loading data" ServiceMethod="BindQueryType" ServicePath="~/Query/DropDownWebService.asmx"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>Specify query type</b><br />
             <asp:NoValidationDropDown ID="ddlitem" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlitem_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
            <%--<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlitem" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlitem_SelectedIndexChanged"/>--%>
            <ajaxtoolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="ccditem" runat="server" Category="ItemType" TargetControlID="ddlitem" ParentControlID="ddlquery"
            PromptText="Please specify query type" LoadingText="Loading data" ServiceMethod="BindItemType" ServicePath="~/Query/DropDownWebService.asmx"/>
        </p>
        <p>
```

This is an excerpt from my WebService.cs file:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using AjaxControlToolkit;
using System.Web.Services;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CascadingDropdown
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "NewWebApp")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()]
public class DropDownWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    //Database connection string
    private static string strconnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    //database connection
    SqlConnection conquery = new SqlConnection(strconnection);
    public DropDownWebService()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components
        //InitializeComponent();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// WebMethod to Populate Query Dropdown
    /// </summary>
    [WebMethod]
    public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] BindQueryType(string knownCategoryValues, string category)
    {
        conquery.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdquery = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from QueryTypes", conquery);
        cmdquery.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter daquery = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdquery);
        DataSet dsquery = new DataSet();
        daquery.Fill(dsquery);
        conquery.Close();
        //create list and add items in it by looping through dataset table
        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> querydetails = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
        foreach (DataRow dtrow in dsquery.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            string Id = dtrow["Id"].ToString();
            string Query = dtrow["Query"].ToString();
            querydetails.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(Query, Id));
        }
        return querydetails.ToArray();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// WebMethod to Populate Item Dropdown
    /// </summary>
    [WebMethod]
    public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] BindItemType(string knownCategoryValues, string category)
    {
        //int Id;
        //This method will return a StringDictionary containing the name/value pairs of the currently selected values
        StringDictionary querydetails = AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDown.ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(knownCategoryValues);
        string Id = querydetails["QueryType"].ToString();
        conquery.Open();
        SqlCommand cmditem = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, Item from ItemTypes where QueryId=@QueryId", conquery);
        cmditem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QueryId", Id);
        cmditem.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter daitem = new SqlDataAdapter(cmditem);
        DataSet dsitem = new DataSet();
        daitem.Fill(dsitem);
        conquery.Close();

        //create list and add items in it by looping through dataset table
        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> itemdetails = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
        foreach (DataRow dtrow in dsitem.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            string ItemId = dtrow["Id"].ToString();
            string Item = dtrow["Item"].ToString();
            itemdetails.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(Item, ItemId));
        }
        return itemdetails.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And here is my WebService.asmx file:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="DropDownWebService" CodeBehind="~/Query/DropDownWebService.cs" %>
```

Thanks guys for any comments!